# Ubuntu installer stuck at "configuring boot loader..."

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I dual-booted my windows with Ubuntu 14.10

Due to some failed upgrades, there was something wrong with most of my drivers...

The sound wasn't working eventhough the speaker test works and the wifi only shows "no network devices available" eventhough I can online

After a while of struggle, I decided to reinstall it

So far, the Ubuntu 15 installer was showing some kind of nouveau error [UNK08] before rebooting

The Ubuntu 14.10 installer I installed before stuck at "configuring boot loader"

I tried running bootrec /fixmbr and bootrec /fixboot using windows repair disc, the installer still repeats the same thing

What else can I do..?

Answer (score 0):

Exit and try to reinstall the operating system. If the operating system is damaged as it probably is restarting the installation process will do it no harm. If for some reason you have an option to update the ubuntu system on harddisk when you start up again chose ERASE AND REINSTALL.

If this fails it could be a problem with the copy of Ubuntu try downloading it again.

If the problem is persistent try with a new USB.

Hope you succeed!

Comment: Ok...this might take some time

Answer (score 0):

You can try Boot Repair before reinstalling your OS. It will regenerate your GRUB and boot installation.

1- You can run it from Ubuntu:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt install --assume-yes boot-repair
boot-repair
```

2- Or you can create a live USB: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Hope this helps.